# SilverLight Socket Issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets

I'm trying write a silverlight application, socket can connect to 127.0.0.1:4505 but arg.completed event doesn't work

```
arg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 4505);
            arg.UserToken = sck;
            arg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(arg_Completed);
            sck.ConnectAsync(arg);

void arg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = "Durum!";
            if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Connect)
            {
                label1.Content = "Bağlandı!";
            }          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that `ConnectAsync` may not be completing asynchronously.  Have a read of its documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

You should be testing the returned boolean value from `ConnectAsync`, if its `true` then the completed event will fire, if not then the operation completed synchronously and `ConnectAsync` will not fire.  The fact that you are using the local 127.0.0.01 increases the likelyhood for a synchronous completion.

On a synchronous connection the args object you passed into the call will have been mutated accordingly.